# Parsing difficult date in the java

Tags: java, date

I have a problem with parsing my data, I have data from twitter API in format like:

```
2014-03-19 23:51:10 +0000
```

And the question is how would I parse that date into format lets say US, with beign dd/mm/yy and 23/51 AM
I am bad at parsing dates and couldnt find any good solution.
Thanks for help

Comment: or http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH/mm a");
    Date myDate = inputFormat.parse("2014-03-19 23:51:10 +0000");
    System.out.println(outputFormat.format(myDate));
```

Comment: +0000 is probably a timezone

Comment: Not excatly what I wanted, look at the question. I dont know why I did got two downvotes, I didnt even got answer, simpledateformat from njzk  did really impress me.

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you very much, I have been so confused with the dates.. You have saved my day.

Comment: probably got 2 down votes because it's a very easy question to answer via a google search. The format you are parsing is very nearly ISO 8601 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601